# Is there any way to get mhtml content of a webpage with an SDK module?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In Chrome extensions there is a function to get MHTML content of the page as base64 code. Is there any feature in the Firefox SDK to do the same?

Comment: Yes these two addons do that - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unmht/?src=ss and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/?src=ss

Comment: does not need me a exists plugin, need me to make it in my plugin..

Comment: Those addons are open source, open up the code and see how they did it.